# Android mix audio into a playing stream

Tags: android, audio

I am looking for a way to mix an audio into an already-playing mixed audio stream. For example, when a sound is being played half way through, I want to add in another sound to play together without interrupting the first sound to continue. I would also like to have an ability to withdraw a playing sound stream from the mixed playing stream. Going through Android's relevant document, I think that the only possible solution is to use native OpenSL ES via JNI to develop my own library where I can programmatically mix in/take out an audio stream from mixed audio streams. I would like to hear if anyone has a way to achieve it with less effort.

Thank you
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `SoundPool`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html